# Mac OS X Server app hangs during Upgrading services

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I have upgraded my mac mini server to Mavricks and installed the new Server app.  When I run the Server app, it stops at the stage "Upgrading services" and never ends.  Any idea how to investigate whats going wrong?

Comment: The last line in the log says: 
service state not restored from previous settings (reason: no launchd state found from service)

and noting after that.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting /Library/Server and installing the Server.app solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue upgrading to Server 4 on Yosemite. Renamed the /Library/Server to /Library/_Server and did a re-install. It indeed solved the issue. Some settings were restored, but my Host Names were gone.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a less drastic solution: remove the data folder for the offending service:

/Library/Server/...service.../Data/

[https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6719014?start=0&tstart=0]